# php password_verify doesn't work

Tags: php, password-hash

This should be very straight forward: I'm generating a hashed password and then want to compare it to the "unhashed" string. It always returns invalid password. What am I missing?

```
<?php

// MY CURRENT PHP VERSION IS 7.0.9

$password = "abc";

$options = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
];
$password_hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";

if (password_verify($password, $password_hashed)) {
    echo '<strong>correct password.</strong><br>';
} else {
    echo '<strong>invalid password!</strong><br>';
}


?>
```

Comment: `."\n";` at the end there. It adds a newline to the end of the hashed password string. Remove it.

Comment: Also, using your own `salt` is deprecated as of PHP 7.0.

Comment: Thx a lot for your reply. So what would I do instead of using my own salt?

Comment: Nothing, let PHP deal with it. But your current issue is the newline being added through the `\n` at the end of your hash.

Comment: that worked, thanks a lot! i can mark you as the right answer if you put it in an answer.

Comment: Always read the manual in its entirety. A [user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017) clearly states the issue that caused the problem.

Comment: thx for your comment, it's not a user contributed note though, it actually is an official expample in the PHP manual, but there it is echoed out and not assigned to a variable. so when echoed out it just adds the new line after echoing the hashed password. but when copied without looking too closely and put in a variable, as i did, then the outcome is the error above. i bet i'm not first one who "mal-copied" this ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is that you are adding a newline at the end of the hashed string.

```
$password_hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
//                                                                       ^
//                                          Here you add a newline ------'
```

That means that you hash the password, and add a newline at the end of the hashed string. When you now compare against the unhashed string through `password_verify()`, it won't match - simply because of that newline. To solve the issue, you need to remove `."\n"` from where you hash the password, making it...

```
$password_hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

The newline probably comes from the PHP manual, where they show examples of hashing the passwords. Unfortunately, it's quite misleading - and should in my opinion be removed from the examples.

As a final note, from the manual.

> **Warning**
>   The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.

- [`password_hash()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)